# I am not able to write in LatEx anyone have an idea?

Tags: latex

I am using the graphy theme and working on a page right now, but I am not able to write in LatEx?[image: Here is a link to my code and I was putting in a HTML block]

Comment: WordPress doesn't support Latex, you need a plugin for that.